# Error when compiling project in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have this error when compiling a Multi project in gradle in the intellij editor, in Linux it works normally but in windows I have this error

`Cannot locate tasks that match ':maintenance-service:MaintenanceServiceApplication.main()' as project 'maintenance-service' not found in root project 'maintenance-service'.

- Try:

> Run gradle projects to get a list of available projects.
> For more on name expansion, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:name_abbreviation in the Gradle documentation.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> BUILD FAILED in 943ms

`

I have tested it on a Linux operating system and it works normally but on Windows it gives me an error.

Comment: Do you mean a multi-module project?